# 1. Two sum Leetcode. Time limit exceeded

Tags: python

On two sum problem on leetcode i pass the test cases but when i submit i get "Time Limit Exceeded". Why does this not happen to other people, is it a problem in my code?

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:

        b1, a1 = 0,0

        while b1<len(nums):
            while a1<len(nums):
                if b1 != a1:
                    if nums[b1] + nums[a1] == target:
                        return a1, b1
                else:
                    a1 += 1  
            b1 += 1
            a1 = 0
```

Comment: It seens like your program is taking a long while to give it is  answer you should try to solve it in a more optimal way

Comment: I think the "else: a1 += 1" needs another indent, or at least another else a1 += 1 in the scope of the nums[b1]+nums[a1]==target scope

Comment: if you know how to use a flow chart... i suggest you build one for the this function

Comment: your answer time complexity is `O(n^2)` try to think of more optimized way to solve the problem hint using `hashmap`

Answer (score 0):

Optimized from  `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` [Time Complexity]

**Using hashmap:-**

Time Complexity-`O(n)` Space Complexity-`O(n) [for the dictionary]`

**Note** `if(remaining in hashmap)` -: **The in operator for dictionary has average case time-complexity of O(1)**

**Code:-**

```
hashmap={}
for index,value in enumerate(nums):
    remaining=target-nums[index]
    if(remaining in hashmap):  #check in keys of the dictionary
        return [hashmap[remaining],index]
    hashmap[value]=index 
return -1 #If no two sum can give the target value
```